# ElasticSearch Script get value of current year

Tags: date, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I'm trying to make a script within my rescore function to check if the bibliographic release date (doc['bibliografische_verschijningsdatum']), is the same as the commercial release date (doc['verschijningsdatum']).

AND the doc['verschijningsjaar'].value == new Date.getYear()

**How can I get the year of todays date in painless?**

```
"script_score": {
          "script": "((doc['verschijningsdatum'] == doc['bibliografische_verschijningsdatum']) && (doc['verschijningsjaar'].value == new Date().getYear()) ? 1 : 0)"
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has already been asked [on the elastic forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/painless-get-date-today/81264). The official answer, at least from a member of the elastic team, is the following, (emphasis is mine):

> **Painless intentionally doesn't have any access to now style variables** so they can be better cached. The current recommendation is for you to **send now style variables in over scripts params**.
>
> BTW, you should know that this query isn't able to take advantage of the index at all. It'll have to load the @timestamp field for every document and compare it. This much much slower than extracting the day of the week on ingest and adding it to the document.